# JS/DOM, perf: Should you try to use as few event listeners as possible?

Tags: javascript, performance

Let's say I have 10000 elements in DOM that need to respond to mouse movement, e.g. each rotates towards the mouse.

I wonder about two approaches a) adding a DOM event listener for every element individually and b) adding a single DOM event listener, then iterating an array of 10000 elements manually.

Some simple tests show basically no difference in performance for me.

I conclude that trying to minimize the number of event listeners is an unnecessary "optimization" and can be safely omitted.

Can you think of any reasons to keep the number of DOM event listeners down? Or would you say there's no need to try to optimize in that regard?